# How to get specific columns in Laravel [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel]

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, phpoffice

the file i am importing has thousands of records which is causing my network to get slow. i want to read only those columns that i need, before inserting it into database. When file is processed , it should first search those columns not the whole file, and fetch the rows of those columns

```
Excel::load($path, function($reader) {

//Getting headers using this


       $headers = $reader->first()->keys()->toArray();

//This is the array of required columns

       $headings = array('registrant_name','registrant_address','registrant_phone','registrant_zip','registrant_email','registrant_country','registrant_state','registrant_city');


});
```

**Data insertion after file read.**

```
 if($data->count() > 0)
             {
              foreach($data->toArray() as $value)
              {
                $insert[] = array(
                 'registrant_name'  => $value['registrant_name'],
                 'registrant_address'   => $value['registrant_address'],
                 'registrant_phone'   => $value['registrant_phone'],
                 'registrant_zip'   => $value['registrant_zip'],
                 'registrant_email'   => $value['registrant_email'],
                 'registrant_country'   => $value['registrant_country'],
                 'registrant_state'   => $value['registrant_state'],
                 'registrant_city'   => $value['registrant_city']

                );                
               }
              }


      if(!empty($insert))
      {
       DB::table('customers')->insert($insert);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In collections, you can check the method *only* [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-only)

i.e.

```
$headers = $reader->first()->only(['registrant_name','registrant_address','registrant_phone','registrant_zip','registrant_email','registrant_country','registrant_state','registrant_city']);
```

You might also use *chunk*, to insert the data in smaller collections than in one big.

Could you update the post with the App\Import class in order to help you more.